# Append to existing JSX instead of using if-else conditional logic

Tags: reactjs

In my react classes, I often find myself having to use conditional logic to decide what to render. The problem with such an approach is that it leads to a lot of redundant markup. Here is an example:

```
if(this.props.quotes) {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="item-1">{this.props.header}</div>
            <div className="item-2">Add content...</div>
            <i className="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            <i className="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
        </div>
    );
}
else {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="item-1">{this.props.header}</div>
            <div className="item-2">Add content...</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The only difference between the two HTML components is that one has two extra font-awesome elements. Ideally, you would want to use some base markup, and append content to it based on the result of the conditional.

I tried the following approach where I put the HTML content into an array and pushed the extra HTML elements in if the condition `this.props.quotes` was met:

```
var cardContent = [
    <div className="item-1">{this.props.header}</div>, 
    <div className="item-2">Add content...</div>
];

if(this.props.quotes) {
    cardContent.push(<i className="fa fa-quote-left"></i>);
    cardContent.push(<i className="fa fa-quote-right"></i>);
}

return (
    <div className="card">
        {cardContent}
    </div>
);
```

This introduces a new problem, mainly that React complains about missing key props in the array:

`Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

In this context, it doesn't make sense to give the elements keys since 3/4 of the content is static (the only non-static element is `{this.props.header}`).

---

Is there a better way of appending to existing JSX than the method I outlined above? I don't want to suppress all unique key prop warnings since it is still valid in the case of mapping. Is it better to just accept the redundant HTML approach?

Comment: Bump. I was wondering this yesterday.

Comment: In this specific case, I would use quotes as the `content` of `before` and `after` pseudo-elements of the div itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you render an Array of JSX elements, each one must have a `key` property on them. As you construct your array, you can do something like

```
cardContent.push(<div className="item-1" key="item-1">..</div>)
cardContent.push(<div className="item-2" key="item-2">..</div>)
```

I also want to mention for the example you've described, your elements are simple enough that having an *inline* condition rather than having two blocks that you conditionally return

```
return (
  <div className="card">
    <div className="item-1">{this.props.header}</div>
    <div className="item-2">Add content...</div>
    {this.props.quotes && <i className="fa fa-quote-left"></i>}
    {this.props.quotes && <i className="fa fa-quote-right"></i>}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Also in general, if you're having a pain with ugly conditions, I made this the other month. Perhaps you could find it useful https://github.com/ajwhite/render-if